# PHP: when going to end point it is not found locally but found remotely

Tags: php, laravel

sorry for this question I am extremely new to PHP/Laravel ( I am a Node user and have to dig through this legacy code). I have a server running locally but whenever I use Postman to check some of the endpoints I keep getting a response of 500 Server error.
I ran the command `$ php artisan serve --port=8000` and get the response back:

> Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000

now whenever I try and send any request [localhost:8000/getTowns] to the server I get a 500 error and in the terminal there is no stack trace or errors being shown it is completely empty.

Now when I launch the server with the command `$ php -S localhost:8000` I get:

> PHP 7.1.23 Development Server started at Wed Nov 13 12:55:52 2019
>
> Listening on http://localhost:8000
>
> Document root is /Users/user/Desktop/legacy
>
> Press Ctrl-C to quit.

then when making any request I get

```
[Wed Nov 13 12:56:06 2019] ::1:59504 [404]: /getTowns - No such file or directory
[Wed Nov 13 12:56:07 2019] ::1:59505 [404]: /favicon.ico - No such file or directory
```

I don't know whatever information is relevant for this, but, I will update with more relevent code when requested. Thanks!

*update:*
Looking in the logs, I see a lot of:

```
laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined.

laravel.ERROR: Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure. {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure.
```

Comment: hi, sorry made sure they were all on the same port it was just a typo from me, but the error is still the same

Comment: Any difference between using 127.0.0.1 and localhost?  What's the output of `host localhost`?

Comment: issue is the same

Comment: did you 'composer install' prior to running `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: What if you omit the getTowns part? a 500 response code implies logic error.

Comment: yes if I omit that part it is still the same 500 error

Comment: Any logs under `storage/logs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a silly thing or a typo in the question, but the message posted says that the laravel dev server runs on port 3000. The requests you are making are on port 8000. If your ports are in fact correct (aka, the default 8000, for example), my best guess is that you haven't run 
`composer install` in the project root folder ('legacy').

For the php native server, you are starting it in your 'legacy' folder where the project is located. Laravel projects should have their webroot in the 'public' folder of the project (aka 'legacy/public' - I would assume, in your case).

---

EDIT:
as per being unable to run `composer install` successfully:

the issue is a route that may look like this:

```
Route::get('/some/route', function() {
   return 'Hello World';
});
```

this route uses a Closure, which can't be serialized. You should update it so that it uses a Controller method.

Something like

```
Route::get('/some/route', 'UserController@getIndex');
```

Cheers!

Comment: it was a typo I checked and they are all working on the same

Comment: @Ctfrancia . - what if you start the native php server (php -S localhost:8000) from the public folder inside legacy, instead of the actual legacy folder? Also, have you run `composer install -o` in the 'legacy' folder ?

Comment: I ran the command where the `composer.lock` file is located and following the command I am now getting an error: In Route.php line 917:
                                                                
  Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure.  
                                                                

Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

Comment: @Ctfrancia in this case the issue is fairly clear. You are using a route definition somewhere that uses a Closure function. I've updated my answer. But for the initial question it should be clear that being unable to run composer install is a core issue.

Comment: your update solved the error with the routes, there was one that was like mentioned. I think that since it is legacy and following some other stackoverflow questions and answers is that I updated from an old version to a new version and the things that have changed... this is going to get ugly haha! thanks for your hellp!